# when i click check all all the records is selected even in the next page records(in javascript table)

Tags: javascript

I am showing checkbox,article title,description,status in table(using javascript table which as sorting etc)

when i have 20 records,the table display 10 records per page,when i click checkall all the records selected i.e the 2 page records also selected...

i want to be like this ,when i click checkall one the page showing should be checked...

how to do that in javascript?

my script to checkall is this

```
function Checkall(){
    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        if (this.checked == false) {
            //$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', this.checked);
            this.checked = true;
            $("#checkall").val("UnCheck All");
        } else {
            this.checked = false;
            $("#checkall").val("Check All");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$("INPUT[type='checkbox']:visible")`

to select only visible check boxes